# How to Dispose ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, dispose, idisposable

Hi 
When i use following code:

```
 myManualResetEvent.Dispose();
```

Compiler gives this error:

```
 'System.Threading.WaitHandle.Dispose(bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

howevr following line works fine:

```
 ((IDisposable)myManualResetEvent).Dispose();
```

is it the correct way to dispose or at runtime it might crash in some scenerios.

Thanks.

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with your example code.  If compiler gives " 'System.Threading.WaitHandle.Dispose(bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level." error  you had to either use  myManualResetEvent.Dispose(true); or  myManualResetEvent.Dispose(false);
not  myManualResetEvent.Dispose();

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The designers of the .NET Base Class Library decided to implement the `Dispose` method using [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx):

```
private void IDisposable.Dispose() { ... }
```

The `Dispose` method is private and the only way to call it is to cast the object to `IDisposable` as you have discovered.

The reason this is done is to customize the name of the `Dispose` method into something that better describes how the object is disposed. For a `ManualResetEvent` the customized method is the `Close` method.

To dispose a `ManualResetEvent` you have two good options. Using `IDisposable`:

```
using (var myManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false)) {
  ...
  // IDisposable.Dispose() will be called when exiting the block.
}
```

or calling `Close`:

```
var myManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
...
// This will dispose the object.
myManualResetEvent.Close();
```

You can read more in the section [Customizing a Dispose Method Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=VS.100).aspx#Anchor_0) in the design guideline *Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources* on MSDN:

> Occasionally a domain-specific name is more appropriate than `Dispose`. For example, a file encapsulation might want to use the method name `Close`. In this case, implement `Dispose` privately and create a public `Close` method that calls `Dispose`.

Answer (score 3):

[`WaitHandle.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.close.aspx)

> This method is the public version of
>   the IDisposable.Dispose method
>   implemented to support the IDisposable
>   interface.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384809.aspx), `WaitHandle.Dispose()` and `WaitHandle.Close()` are equivalent. `Dispose` exists to allow closing though the `IDisposable` interface. For manually closing a WaitHandle (such as a ManualResetEvent), you can simply use `Close` directly instead of `Dispose`:

> **[WaitHandle.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.close.aspx)**
>
> [...]
>   This method is the public version of the IDisposable.Dispose method implemented to support the IDisposable interface.