# Dispose object correctly

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

Im using VS and a marking in my code tells me to :

**"... runChange that is of IDisposable ... change dispose() to dispose object".**

But how would i do it correctly - if i put the code in the form.designer's autogenerated dispose() function it says :

**"WaitHandle.Dispose(bool) is inaccesible due to protection level"**

here is the objects that i want to dispose:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        private readonly AutoResetEvent runChange = new AutoResetEvent(false);
....
```

Here is my try to Dispose:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
       if (disposing && (components != null))
       {
           components.Dispose();
       }

       runChange.Dispose(true);

       base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Comment: Just call `runChange.Dispose();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Dispose ManualResetEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270701/how-to-dispose-manualresetevent)

Comment: https://factorycode.wordpress.com/2019/02/01/idisposable-interface/

Comment: That implementation is wrong. You could be calling `runChange.Dispose` from `TestForm`'s finalizer; that is never a good idea. You should only be disposing managed objects if `disposing` is true.

Comment: Above works on orher objects, but as written, the runChange.Dispose() call generate a protection level compiler error ??

That is what i dont understand

Comment: The interface might be explicitly implemented; try `((IDisposable)runChange).Dispose()`

Comment: Ahhh - Sinatr - The .Close() call does it :-)

Thanks